# How to see the response data of a JS (which has a Post Ajax call ) in JMeter

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, jmeter

I'm new to JMeter. I'm currently blocked in a scenario where I would need to Parameterize a Request data which is the response of a Javascript which has a Post Ajax call like below :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:50001/api/Xyz/Xyz",
        dataType: "json",
        data: Request,
        async: isAsync
})...
```

Only If can see the response of this JS call in JMeter I would be able to Parameterize.

Please correct me if there is another way to solve this.

I would appreciate your inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always something like postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) to check the response.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is not a browser, it's a load generation tool. It can produce HTTP traffic, but it does not actually parse/execute JavaScript coming with the loaded page.

If you need to load test your AJAX application, then you can easily simulate HTTP traffic coming from normal browser requests and from AJAX requests.

For more information, on "How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter",check the [link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the response for this call you need to execute this call using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler by sending a [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request to your `https://localhost:50001/api/Xyz/Xyz` URL. Don't forget to add HTTP Header Manager and set it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

Also be aware that due to the nature of the [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) calls (`A` stands for `asynchronous`) you need to put this request (and all other AJAX requests if any) under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter). You can install Parallel Sampler and Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).